# What exactly does it mean to choose a vector from {0,1} raised to a particular power?

Tags: vectors

[image]

This excerpt from [Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/486966.Probability_and_Computing). Lemma 1.5 explains that choosing from r = {0,1}^n is the same as choosing independently and unifromly from {0,1}. What exactly does it mean to choose a vector from {0,1}^n?

Comment: Some day Google will be able to search for mathematical conventions/notations, and such questions will be closed. [Cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power)

Comment: $A^n=A\times A\times A\times\cdots \times A$, $n$-times

Comment: @user202729 But this question is not on the website as of right now. So, it should still be valid!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Searching Google for `{0,1}^n` brings up [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/0-1-n-and-0-1n-notations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As finite probability spaces, the choice of $\bar r$ and each of the $r_i$ differ.

A finite probability space, is a set of outcomes (a sample space), combined with an assignment of a probability to each element ( the probability that that outcome happens), such that the sum of the probabilities of all elements is one.

For example, $\{1,2,3\}$ is a probability space, with the assignment $P(1) = P(2) = P(3) = \frac 13$.

Here, $\bar r$ comes from the finite probability space $\Lambda = \{0,1\}^n$, where each element, which is a vector, has the probability $\frac 1{2^n}$.

On the other hand, each of the $r_i$ comes from the finite probability space $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ with $P(0)=P(1) = \frac12$, and the combined output which we write as $(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)$ comes from the probability distribution $\Omega\ \times ... \times \Omega$ $k$ times.

The lemma says that as probability spaces, the spaces $\Omega^k$, and $\Lambda$ are isomorphic, and this looks trivial when you do not have the necessary abstraction to back it up. Even with the abstraction, it is a very easy proof.

EDIT : Let me give the example $n = 2$.  Then, the elements of $\Lambda$ are $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ . Each one would occur with probability $\frac{1}{2^2} = \frac14$.

$\color{red}{\text{Here , note the  fact  that we  have  enclosed vectors in circular brackets}}$.

Note that here we are dealing with $\Omega^2 = \Omega \times \Omega$. What are the elements of $\Omega \times \Omega$? They look **remarkably similar** to those  of $\Lambda$, $\color{red}{\text{but not the same}}$.

The elements of $\Omega^2$ are :

$[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]$, where $[a,b] \color{red}{\text{ is the formal tuple consisting of a and b}}$, not the vector containing $a$ and $b$. I have used square brackets to indicate the fact that this is a tuple, not a vector. Each tuple will have probability one quarter.

Now, the isomorphism from one space to other is almost obvious : $[a,b] \leftrightarrow (a,b)$.

In future, these spaces can therefore be interchanged (and confused without any problem!) for each other.

Comment: Ahh, this is an amazing answer, but I am still confused as to what {0,1}^n is. If you could modify your answer to reflect that with an example, I would be very grateful!

Comment: I will edit it then.

Comment: Yes, I think my edit should suffice now.

Comment: Yes! Perfect Answer! thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is any set then $S^n$ conventionally means the "product" of $n$ copies of $S$; that is, an element of $S^n$ is a choice of an ordered $n$-tuple consisting of one element from the first copy of $S$, then one element from the second copy of $S$, and so on up to the $n$-th copy.

In particular $\{0,1\}^n$ is isomorphic to the set of strings of bits (taking value $0$ or $1$) of length $n$.

Comment: Can you give me examples for different values of *n*?

Comment: n=2 is a square; n=3 is a cube; n=4 is a tesseract, etc. @SharanDuggirala

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general, let $A$ be a set. Then, we note with $A^n$, for every $n\geq1$, the set of all finite sequences with length $n$ that consist of elements from $A$.

So, in our case, where $A=\{0,1\}$, $\{0,1\}^n$ is the set of all sequences of length $n$, let us say $s=(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$, such that:
$$s_i\in\{0,1\}\text{ for every }i=1,2,\dots,n$$
So, to choose such a sequence $s$, for instance $s=(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)\in\{0,1\}^{8}$ we have to define each of its elements seperately, which actually means that we choose each element of $s$ independently with respect to the others.

Expanding this a little bit, you can see that such sequences are **exactly** all the functions $f$ from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $A$. So, we also note with $A^n$ the set of all the functions
$$f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to A$$
With that in mind, we can see that, if $A,B$ are two sets (whicever sets, for instance $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\{p(x):p\text{ is a polynomial of $x$}\}$) we can define $A^B$ to be the set of all functions $f$ from $B$ to $A$, or, symbolically:
$$A^B:=\{f:B\to A|\text{where $f$ is a function}\}$$
So with that in mind, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all real functions with real values and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all sequences with real values - every real sequence can be considered to be a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and vice versa.